# Package build failure on Hackage

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I uploaded my first package to Hackage ( http://hackage.haskell.org/package/groundhog-0.0.1) and it failed to build with error:

```
*** setup configure

Configuring groundhog-0.0.1...
cabal-setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
monad-control ==0.2.*, pool ==0.1.*
```

This package builds fine on my machine and in a test environment which had only Haskell Platform installed. I tried to ensure that the latest cabal is used and uploaded another version with dependency on Cabal 1.10. Later I found In Cabal FAQ that this error can arise if the packages our package depends on were build with --user and configure is run with --global. However many other packages depend on monad-control and pool and they are ok. Hackage should apply the same flags to all packages so I don't think it is the same issue as in the FAQ.

I think I missed something. Could you help me with the build?

I want to announce Groundhog persistence library when the documentation on Hackage is generated.

Comment: Have you ever managed to make it work? This library looks very promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no obvious reason for the failure. Here's [the package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/groundhog-0.0.1). The likely reason is that for one reason or another those packages aren't exposed on Hackage at the moment.

You should contact the libraries mailing list to ask about the state of those libraries on Hackage.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that hackage isn't using cabal-dev to sandbox the builds.  I think more builds on hackage would succeed if we "upgraded" to cabal-dev.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, packages that introduce executables (like monad-control, judging form its .cabal file) must be installed manually. Both groundhog and pool depends on monad-control. Simply install monad-control manually first (cabal install monad-control). Then it should work.